# django filtering translated fields

Tags: django

I am using [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) and have project with 4 languages. Model field i am filtering is translated to 4 different languages with [modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation). Problem is, **i can't filter with all languages.** It works only with default. Filtering code:

```
enums = attribute.enum_group.enums.all()
choices = [('', '-')] + [(x.value, x.value) for i, x in enumerate(enums)]
lookup = 'variants__eav_values__value_enum__value'
#value_enum__value is translated to 4 languages
self.filters[attribute.slug] = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
                                                label=attribute.name,
                                                name=lookup,
                                                choices=choices
                                                )
```

So basically this creates drop-down filter and populates it with choices. `name=lookup` is same as `SomeProduct.objects.filter(variants__eav_values__value_enum__values='someval')`.
 Now as i said it works fine with default, english. If i switch to other languages, filtering doesn't work. I think for some reason it doesn't change current language. Also, if i hardcode language, `lookup = 'variants__eav_values__value_enum__value_ru'` it would work. But this is silly solution. Is there any way to make this work nice?